# Docker: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7 as python
CMD ["bash"]

FROM ubuntu
COPY --from=python /usr/local /usr/local
```

Then,

```
docker build -t ubuntuapp .
docker run ubuntuapp /usr/local/bin/python
```

Output:

```
local/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

so, I ran

```
 docker run ubuntubr ls /usr/local/lib
```

Output

```
libpython2.7.so
libpython2.7.so.1.0
pkgconfig
python2.7
```

so why cant it find libpython2.7.so.1.0 when it exists in /usr/local/lib and how do i fix it?

thank you

Comment: Set environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add /usr/local/lib to the list of directories that the linker searches at runtime, and run `ldconfig`.  Append these 2 lines to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf && \
    ldconfig
```

Then I test it with ubuntuapp:

```
$ docker run --rm -it test /usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Dec 12 2017, 16:55:09) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```